# Is there a way to specify to Spring that a bean should be used upon initialization and then immediately discarded?

Tags: java, spring

I'm interested to know if there is an interface that I can use to tell Spring to start a particular bean up, invoke its initialization procedure (either as an InitializingBean via afterPropertiesSet(), or via an init-method, or some other way), and then throw it away.

My use case is a simple "sanity-checker" that will check the database for valid values upon startup for a web application.  Although the overhead would be small for our particular bean, keeping that bean for all eternity in the application context is pointless, as once the bean had initialized, it is no longer needed.

I'm sure there are other use cases for this type of behavior, but I haven't found anything like this yet in Spring.

In particular, I'm looking for it in the Java variant of Spring, I have access to 3.x and up as needed.

EDIT: based on the accepted answer, the following is a simple hack to provide the solution:

```
public final class NullReturningBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private List<String> beanNamesToDiscard = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link NullReturningBeanPostProcessor} instance.
     */
    public NullReturningBeanPostProcessor() {
    super();
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (beanNamesToDiscard.contains(beanName)) {
        return null;
    }
    return bean;
    }

    public void setBeanNamesToDiscard(List<String> beanNamesToDiscard) {
    if (beanNamesToDiscard != null) {
        this.beanNamesToDiscard = beanNamesToDiscard;
    }
    }
}
```

Placing this bean post processor with the appropriate beans to discard in the application context will make them null, and eligible for garbage collection after they've been initialized.  The bean configuration metadata, unfortunately, will still remain in the application context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this, I would make that bean implement `BeanPostProcessor` and then:

```
@Override
Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
    throws BeansException {
    return bean == this ? null : bean;
}
```

This should cause the ApplicationContext to discard it but only after it has performed the initialization steps.

Note that you also need to implement `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` and there just write `return bean;`.

---

Update: this does NOT work. But not due to MetroidFan2002's comment (see bellow), but due to another part of the JavaDoc:

> ApplicationContexts can autodetect BeanPostProcessor beans in their
>     bean definitions and apply them to any beans subsequently created.

So obviously you cannot apply a BeanPostProcessor to itself.
Sorry for the false alarm :)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't actually do what I'm looking for.  From the documentation:  Returns: the bean instance to use, either the original or a wrapped one; if null, no subsequent BeanPostProcessors will be invoked.  That means if null is returned no subsequent BeanPostProcessors will be invoked - that doesn't mean the ApplicationContext will disgard the bean.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002: Returning `null` does work, as the value returned by the `BeanPostProcessor` is the one associated with the bean name and `null` is allowed; the original bean is discarded. But this solution doesn't work due to another (crucial) aspect -- see my edit.

Comment: this makes me wonder how a question gets 4 upvotes, if it's simply not working. no disrespect to the author! i just wonder on what basis some decide whether to upvote an answer or not.

Comment: @martin: I would just say the 4 up-votes mean "nice try" (no disrespect to the author either !) :D

Comment: You're right, the docs, as usual, are blatantly incorrect - if null is returned in a BeanPostProcessor, at least for the post process after initialization method, it stores a null for that bean definition in the application context.  Which means you're onto something here, and I'll update your answer if I am able to use it to perform this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` bean definition to execute a method on application context initialization.  Though, you do have to be careful with dependencies if some beans need to be initialized before the method is invoked.  The following would execute the `checkDatabase` method on the bean named `sanityChecker` after `beanA`, `beanB` and `beanC` are initialized:

```
<bean
    id="methodInvoker"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    depends-on="beanA, beanB, beanC"
    lazy-init="false"
    p:singleton="false"
    p:target-method="checkDatabase"
    p:target-object-ref="sanityChecker"
/>

<bean
    id="sanityChecker"
    class="com.example.SanityChecker"
    lazy-init="true"
    scope="prototype"
/>
```

Since `checkDatabase` is a prototype, its lifecycle is not managed by the application context and should be garbage collected after initialization; that's something a unit test could prove out.  `methodInvoker` might also need to be a prototype for `checkDatabase` to be garbage collected.

Comment: Could I inject beanA into sanityChecker?  In my use case, say beanA is a JdbcOperations instance that I wish to use for the query - I wouldn't want beanA to go out of scope, but sanityChecker should go away.  Also, it's just splitting hairs, but a prototype beans' lifecycle is managed by the container in part because it does manage their creation upon requests for the bean.  Still, I like this approach if I can inject something into the prototype bean that's used by the methodInvoker.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002: You could add to the `sanityChecker` bean definition a `p:beanA-ref="beanA"` property to inject a reference to beanA; beanA's scope would not change from how it was defined.  And yes, prototypes are only created by the app context; better wording would be the app context does not manage a prototype bean's full lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another bean to which it makes sense to add this responsibility (for example, an existing bean dealing with application lifecycle) you could have that bean implement `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and do the sanity checking there.   Otherwise I like @Costi's answer.

Comment: That pretty well violates separation of concerns, piggybacking functionality onto an existing class like that.  Plus, future developers would have to read that code when trying to discern bugs in the code that's actually there for real functionality rather than code to just assert things when starting up the application in this use case.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I meant if he has another bean *to which it makes sense* to add the responsibility.   For example, a bean dealing with application lifecycle.   I didn't mean throw it into any old bean.